# How to compile resources like .html in Visual Basic?

Tags: .net, vb.net, compilation

I did an application with WebBrowser in Visual Basic and the .html files are in the project resources and when i build the project this create a folder named "Application files" in that folder there all .html files and .img, .js etc.. How i can compile that files? i want which when build the project only make a .exe or that files but hashed (or something like that), there way to make that?

Thanks for your reply

Comment: How EXACTLY did you add the resources? Is this folder you describe in the output folder along with the EXE or elsewhere?

Comment: I add the resources by dragging the folder to the "resources" folder of the project tree

Comment: Generally speaking, you should be adding your resources to the Resources page of the project properties, not in the Solution Explorer.  If you do use the Solution Explorer then you need to set the Build Action of the file to Embedded Resource.